# Show/Hide a popover menu on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I want to show or hide a menu when hover on block, The issue here is when the `cog` that contains the menu mess up the stucture of the block, is there a way to show it whithout pushing the block?
Here's my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('li.iconItem').hover(
    function(){
        $('.popover',this).css({display: 'block'});
    },
    function(){
        $('.popover',this).css({display: 'none'});
    }
);

$('.block').hover(
    function(){
        $('.iconsWrap',this).css({display: 'block'});
    },
    function(){
        $('.iconsWrap',this).css({display: 'none'});
    }
);

});
```

And here's the CSS:

```
    .contextual-links-region {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
.contextual-links-region-active {
  outline: #999 dashed 1px !important;
}
.popover{
    display:block;
    top: -23px;
    left: 26px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.popover ul li a{
    color: #333 !important;
    display: block;
/*    margin: 0.25em 0;
    padding: 0.25em 1em 0.25em 0.5em;*/
}

.iconItem a i{
    float: left;
}

ul.iconsWrap{}
li.iconItem{display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; position:relative}
```

And please why `The cog`  show up at first ?? 
Here's my [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cu9ys/)
Much appreciated!

Comment: Be aware your HTML markup is invalid, having duplicate IDs. BTW, to get result you are expecting, you should use only CSS

Comment: Start point to finish your code: - [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lejuxume/1/edit) - Good luck!